# Editing strictly for style

Tags: discussion, editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What emphasis to use when referring to words?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363/what-emphasis-to-use-when-referring-to-words)

I’m primarily active over on StackOverflow, forgive me if I am unfamiliar with the conventions here.

In an answer, I used the inline code `backticks` to isolate specific words that were the subject of the answer. Another user, a moderator, edited and replaced all my markup with italics. I don’t care for the look — it is harder for me to read. That is why I purposefully and consciously applied the style of markup that I did.

Not a terribly big deal, however it strikes me as slightly presumptuous to edit strictly to apply one’s own personal formatting preferences to another user’s post. **Is this sort of editing conventional here, and if so, is there an established standard?**

Comment: From my dabblings in MSO, back ticks to format words aren't really looked well on.

Comment: @simchona On MSO, one would use it to highlight function or class names within a sentence, not as formatting on sentences (not as an alternative to bold, for example). The subject at hand on MSO is code, so you use it on code to differentiate it from explanation. Here, words are the subject at hand, so again I used it to differentiate. As you can see by my profile there, I know the ropes. That's not really what I'm asking about, at any rate.

Comment: We don’t like backticks here: they look utterly abominable.  You should use italics for that.

Comment: Is there any reference or style guide? Who is "we"? Is it conventional to edit for strictly style here? Thanks for the -1, but can you answer?

Comment: The convention here is that which prevails in academic studies of language: words, phrases or sentences treated as subjects of discussion are presented in italics. There are, moreover, some highly regarded folks here with strong and well-informed opinions on typography whose judgment we follow. We don't do that much editing, except for ESLs and typos, but formatting's fair game, for the sake of consistency. Finally, this being Meta, the downvote represents disagreement with the opinion expressed.

Comment: @tchrist While I certainly appreciate the abrasiveness of your since-deleted comment, the statement itself didn't seem to be very logical: in addition to bold and italicized text, there are also callout frames, shaded block quotes, and innumerable other forms of layout and formatting that have absolutely nothing to do with the subject at hand, nor is said formatting considered detrimental to the readability or credibility of the content. Quite the reverse, actually.

Comment: *I* think it is slighly presumptuous to label long-established community guidelines as my own personal formatting preferences.

Comment: And to directly answer the other part of your question, yes, I will edit a post for a single hyphen that should be a dash. And not just here; on StackOverflow, too. And on Cooking, Gaming, Photography, and the other 80+ SE sites I am registered on. It's the norm, not an exception.

Comment: If someone re-formatted my answer on SO with style markup that I don't like, I'd roll it back.

Comment: @Chris Even if it were part of the standing community guidelines?

Comment: @simchona No, not if, when asked, I can produce such guidelines without being derisive or belligerent. As an aside, I deleted this question because I received an answer in chat. It was re-opened so it could be edited, down voted, then closed by the same moderator that I'm referring to. It occurs to me that there's an unfriendly undertone being created here by a few users.

Comment: @Chris Reputation on Meta will not, unlike MSO, affect your actual reputation. I think that it's a usual landing spot to find the other question he linked to. Please don't take it as an attack on you--if you would like to discuss anything, feel free to ping me in chat or start a room with me.

Comment: @Chris The existence of edit privileges means you are wrong in your basic premise that your post is your property. It's your post only in the sense that you are the source of it ("genitive of source"). That being so, it is unrealistic for you to expect the community to defer to you on all decisions about readability. Instead you should expect the community to correct it for content as well as for style.

Comment: @Chris: I *did* produce such guidelines without being derisive or belligerent. The only way for me to do so was to undelete this post and close it as a duplicate of said guidelines. "It was re-opened so it could be edited, down voted, then closed by the same moderator that I'm referring to" is dishonest at best. I didn't downvote your question, I didn't edit it; I have *no* idea what your beef is. I honestly do not. Had I deleted the question again right after explaining myself, *that* would have been inappropriate. This is a public venue.

Comment: @RegDwighт "Correct style" is rather subjective. At any rate, the wording of my question is not "this should not happen", but rather "is this conventional, and where are the guidelines?" Observe the sole answer. Guidelines? None. Left-handed barbs at my literacy, professionalism, and equating my post to a "ransom note"? Check. Calling me names in chat? Check. Let's be clear, I didn't come here with anything other than a desire to participate. Now I feel I'm defending myself against mockery, a fruitless pursuit. I've been converted from a willing participant to regretting the attempt.

Comment: @RegDwighт My beef, if you will, is not with the editing, or that there are conventions. MετάEd, I don't believe I own my postings. I perceive actions carried out by certain users to be generally hostile or spiteful. Enumerating examples will probably turn into pettiness, but for a start: the editing of this post to replace single quotes from an standard keyboard with apostrophes (not on a standard keyboard). This is clearly not conventional (see: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/is-there-a-place-to-ask-open-ended-chatty-questions). What is the motivation, do you think?

Comment: @Chris: Your question started out as just that - a *question*, asking about how format standardisation works on ELU. But it seems to have turned into a defence of your right not to have your format choices edited away by others. Standards here on ELU are at best loosely adhered to - but the bottom line is there is some consistency, and most of those who notice at all are more than happy to see RegDwight et al nudge things towards that consistency. I don't bother with matching “quotes” myself (except there!) but it certainly doesn't bother me if others do. (TL;DR: - Loosen up and play nice! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please read my last two comments. You're right that this question has completely derailed (that's why I deleted it to begin with). At this point, I am only defending my "right" to use the site without dealing with hostility from established users. Loosen up an play nice!

Comment: @Chris: I'm not wishing to take sides here, but I am a bit concerned that you're feeling hard done-by. You're obviously a valued member of SO overall, and it's not good for ELU that you should feel unwelcome here. All I can say is I hope you'll continue to contribute on the main site, and just let it pass if someone fiddles with your text formatting again in future. No-one here is in the habit of bearing grudges, I assure you.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, we often edit to polish a posting so that it looks more professional. Yes, RegDwighт♦ does a great deal of work in this regard, as he did with yours, but a lot of the rest of us help out with this too. That means fixing spelling mistakes, punctuation errors, and formatting errors.   Often enough, we will lightly rephrase for clarity.  Think of it as getting a free copyedit.

Doing this makes the site look more appealing, because that way it looks more like a real book, not a ransom letter from a broken typewriter or a txtmsg.  This *is* English Language & Usage, after all.

Backticks have no place here, because they are very gross to look at, and in monospace.  Look at a dictionary: do you see any `inverse video`  crud there?

No.

In a dictionary, one sets an individual word or phrase in an *italic face* to “quote” it so that it stands out from the regular roman.  It’s just how things are done in English.  This is not a programming language.

Comment: tchrist, backticks *do* have a place on this site: they're a workaround to the broken search function, which won't let you search for common words like "that" or "the", but will let you search for them using "code:that" or "code:the" *if and only if* the words are highlighted as code, i.e. `that` or `the`.

Comment: @Marthaª I am aware of the idea, but I don’t think that really works out very well.

Comment: In what way does it not work out very well?

Comment: @Marthaª In many ways.  First and foremost, it only works if you use a repugnant formatting mechanism, which nobody does.  Just use Google, which actually works.